# Whom, who or that?

Tags: grammar, questions, grammatical-case, sentence-starts, whom

Which is the correct sentence?

> Match me only with people I kissed or people **that** I am
>   following

or

> Match me only with people I kissed or people **who** I am
>   following

or

> Match me only with people I kissed or people **whom** I am
>   following

Or are they all wrong?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, loki. Any of the relative pronouns you give (or the zero RP) is allowable in your examples (though 'whom' tends to sound starchy nowadays). But omitting a RP before 'I kissed' and then including one sounds unbalanced and jarring.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks! So how I can rewrite it ? like this: Match me only with people I kissed or people I am following ?

Comment: Yes, or 'Match me only with people that I kissed or people that I am following.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks ! if it's ok for you i will chose the lowest length "Match me only with people I kissed or people I am following"

Comment: The first and third are strictly correct, the second (with "who") although widely used, is viewed as grammatically incorrect by some people (because the "people" are the object, not the subject, of the verb "following").

Comment: @Tim Foster Even Geoff Pullum has said that it's far better to sound natural than to obey antiquated rules.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yeah completely agree, but I wouldn't say it's antiquated quite yet. Maybe in 50 years or so. I usually use "who" in informal speech, and sometimes "whom", but I'm sure there are some older speakers in England (and elsewhere, I'm sure) to whom using "who" would sound wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are correct.

Match me only with people I kissed or people that I am following

Match me only with people I kissed or people whom I am following